# Buscar elemento por atributo, en DOM XML, con Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Quisiera saber como buscar un elemento dentro un archivo XML, pero filtrando por el valor de uno de sus atributos.

Este es el archivo:

```js
<Response state="finalize">
    <Result name="xmlDataManager" type="string">_l_?xml version=_dq_1.0_dq_ encoding=_dq_utf-8_dq_ ?_g__l_Data_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176606_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_9507_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employee=_dq_7880_dq_ name=_dq_ELIZABETH MARTINEZ PLASCENCIA_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176607_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_6982_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employee=_dq_5671_dq_ name=_dq_CINTHYA ANGELICA RIOS CALVILLO_dq_/_g__l_/Data_g_</Result>
    <Result name="emptyTemplate" type="string">1</Result>
    <Result name="xmlData" type="string">_l_?xml version=_dq_1.0_dq_ encoding=_dq_utf-8_dq_ ?_g__l_Data_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348125_dq_ shiftId=_dq_1_dq_ employeeId=_dq_28182_dq_ employee=_dq_13489_dq_ name=_dq_ANA ISABEL DIAZ GRACIAN_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348120_dq_ shiftId=_dq_1_dq_ employeeId=_dq_896_dq_ employee=_dq_4308_dq_ name=_dq_AMADOR BAUTISTA REYES_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348121_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_11876_dq_ employee=_dq_10218_dq_ name=_dq_ADRIAN ALEJANDRO RAMIREZ RAMIREZ_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348122_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_16758_dq_ employee=_dq_12085_dq_ name=_dq_JANET PALACIOS MALDONADO_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348123_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_33089_dq_ employee=_dq_14374_dq_ name=_dq_MARIA GUADALUPE MEDINA DIMAS _dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348124_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employeeId=_dq_16039_dq_ employee=_dq_11372_dq_ name=_dq_LIZETH YOLANDA LUGO HERNANDEZ_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348126_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employeeId=_dq_34550_dq_ employee=_dq_14827_dq_ name=_dq_BRENDA YANETH BELTRAN CUEVAS_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_/Data_g_</Result>
</Response>
```

Necesito obtener:

```
<Result name="xmlDataManager" type="string">_l_?xml version=_dq_1.0_dq_ encoding=_dq_utf-8_dq_ ?_g__l_Data_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176606_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_9507_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employee=_dq_7880_dq_ name=_dq_ELIZABETH MARTINEZ PLASCENCIA_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176607_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_6982_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employee=_dq_5671_dq_ name=_dq_CINTHYA ANGELICA RIOS CALVILLO_dq_/_g__l_/Data_g_</Result>"
```

Lo he logrado con `m_XmlResponse.querySelector("Response Result[name='xmlDataManager']")`

Pero Internet Explorer no es compatible con querySelector(), y necesito que funcione en Chrome e IE.
Además de que debe ser con Javascript y no con JQuery.

Gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿Por qué debes usar Internet Explorar?

Comment: Usa `getElementsByTagName` pasale como argumento Result, posterior indica el índice número 2 y así con `outerHTML` obtienes el resultado esperado

Comment: @EdgarGc lo que pasa es que estamos trabajando en un sistema que desde un inicio se hizo para que funcionara en Internet Explorer(desconozco por qué), y debemos hacer que funcione en los demás navegadores. Por la próxima muerte de IE. Pero mientras acostumbran a todos a usar otro navegador, necesitan que  siga funcionando en IE. Y si cambio algo para que sea compatible en los demás, deja de funcionar para IE.

Comment: @BetaM el problema es que no siempre tendrá el índice 2, El XML es el resultado de una API más dinámica.

Comment: Para que versión de Internet explorer es

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea para la versión 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que necesitas que sea compatible con IE, me parece que esta es la mejor solución, aplicar un `getElementsByTagName` luego convertirlo a un array para esto usamos el  `Array.prototype.slice.call( element )`

> El método slice puede ser usado para convertir objetos parecidos a
> arrays o colecciones a un nuevo Array. Simplemente debe enlazar el
> método al objeto. El  arguments dentro de una función es un ejemplo de
> un objeto parecido a arrays.

```js
function getElement(){
 var element = document.getElementsByTagName('RESULT')
 var arrayElements = Array.prototype.slice.call( element )
 
 for(let i = 0; i < arrayElements.length;i++){
      var attributes = arrayElements[i].attributes
        for(let j = 0; j < attributes.length;j++ ){
        if(attributes[j].name === 'name'){
            if(attributes[j].value === 'xmlDataManager'){
            return arrayElements[i]
          }
      }
    }
 }
 
}
console.log(getElement())
```

```html
<Response state="finalize">
    <Result name="xmlDataManager" type="string">_l_?xml version=_dq_1.0_dq_ encoding=_dq_utf-8_dq_ ?_g__l_Data_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176606_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_9507_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employee=_dq_7880_dq_ name=_dq_ELIZABETH MARTINEZ PLASCENCIA_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_176607_dq_ date=_dq_2020-03-01T00:00:00_dq_ stationId=_dq_348_dq_ employeeId=_dq_6982_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employee=_dq_5671_dq_ name=_dq_CINTHYA ANGELICA RIOS CALVILLO_dq_/_g__l_/Data_g_</Result>
    <Result name="emptyTemplate" type="string">1</Result>
    <Result name="xmlData" type="string">_l_?xml version=_dq_1.0_dq_ encoding=_dq_utf-8_dq_ ?_g__l_Data_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348125_dq_ shiftId=_dq_1_dq_ employeeId=_dq_28182_dq_ employee=_dq_13489_dq_ name=_dq_ANA ISABEL DIAZ GRACIAN_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348120_dq_ shiftId=_dq_1_dq_ employeeId=_dq_896_dq_ employee=_dq_4308_dq_ name=_dq_AMADOR BAUTISTA REYES_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348121_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_11876_dq_ employee=_dq_10218_dq_ name=_dq_ADRIAN ALEJANDRO RAMIREZ RAMIREZ_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348122_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_16758_dq_ employee=_dq_12085_dq_ name=_dq_JANET PALACIOS MALDONADO_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348123_dq_ shiftId=_dq_2_dq_ employeeId=_dq_33089_dq_ employee=_dq_14374_dq_ name=_dq_MARIA GUADALUPE MEDINA DIMAS _dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348124_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employeeId=_dq_16039_dq_ employee=_dq_11372_dq_ name=_dq_LIZETH YOLANDA LUGO HERNANDEZ_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_row detailId=_dq_348126_dq_ shiftId=_dq_3_dq_ employeeId=_dq_34550_dq_ employee=_dq_14827_dq_ name=_dq_BRENDA YANETH BELTRAN CUEVAS_dq_ restCover=_dq_0_dq_ vacationDays=_dq_0_dq_ goalDays=_dq_0_dq_ oilsGoal=_dq_0_dq_ litersGoal=_dq_0_dq_/_g__l_/Data_g_</Result>
</Response>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Me sirvió bastante.